# Check string for similar pattern

Tags: python

I am checking if a filename contains shorthand for a TV show episode, like `S04E02`.

How can I check a string to see if it contains `SxxExx` where `x` is any numeric character?

Comment: You can use regex, like this ``S\d+E\d+``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex, suggested by Sushanth, I can do something like

```
import re

filename = 'some.random.filename.S02E01.mkv'

r = re.search('S\d+E\d+', filename) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an if statement with multiple 'or conditions'

```
if current_char == "0" or current_char == "1" or current_char == "2" ... and so on.
```